# Wamp Server: Multiple Virtual Hosts are not working on Windows

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp, wampserver, virtual-hosts

I have two virtual hosts on windows(for example: test1.dev and test2.dev). But it always load content of test1.dev for both virtual hosts.

Following are my files:

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    test1.dev
127.0.0.1    test2.dev
```

httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName test1.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\test1\public"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName test2.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\test2\public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone recognize the problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you're missing the `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80` line somewhere :)

Comment: I added (NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80) in httpd.conf file and It is OK now.

Answer (score 4):

I did some thing like this 
1- for the local host its :

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
ErrorLog "D:/wamp/www/error.log"
CustomLog D:/wamp/www/access.log common
<Directory "D:/wamp/www">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_access.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2 - and for any other local domain

```
NameVirtualHost zf.local:80
<VirtualHost zf.local:80>
ServerName zf.local
ServerAlias zf.local 
DocumentRoot D:/Workspace/Zend/documentation
ErrorLog "D:/Workspace/Zend/documentation/error.log"
CustomLog D:/Workspace/Zend/documentation/access.log common
<Directory "D:/Workspace/Zend/documentation">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_access.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to write virtual host info into `httpd.conf`. Just uncomment line on which you load `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, then go to this file and put your info there. Should work.

Example of my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: where is httpd-vhosts.conf in windows os directories?

Comment: {wamp-dir}\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\extra\

Comment: Also, check this guide: http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2007/08/16/setting-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp/

Answer (score 1):

You need to include something similar to following line

> `NameVirtualHost *`

Also, it seems you are using https connection to the server which doesn't play well with virtual hosts because of the SSL protocol limitation. The `Host` header in the http request is encrypted and by the time apache decrypts it, it has already passed on the request to one of the virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

> NameVirtualHost *:80

to

> NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check for lines like `"Listen [::0]:80"` in `httpd.conf` and add your ports there too, if `NameVirtualHost` doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Hey guys I've written a very straight forward tutorial which includes the whole process. Let me know if you run into any problems in a comment.

http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/configuring-multiple-domains-within-wamp-for-local-development/

Comment: Don't link to external pages that will possibly be deleted like a _blog_

Comment: The page gives 'Page not found', as it have been predicted.