# wamp vhost servername redirects to wamp homepage instead of the welcome page of CodeIgniter

Tags: wamp

I am a newbie in php using the framework codeigniter. 
I want my servername to be directed to the welcome page of codeigniter.
And while setting up the vhost,
I had problems in vhost servername. 
Everytime I access it, it redirects to the wampserver homepage.

I tried configuring it in the httpd-vhost.conf using this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite"
ServerName mysite.com

</VirtualHost>
```

I uncomment the `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` line
I also included the domain name in windows `host` file.

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

But still, every time I access mysite.com, it shows the wampserver homepage instead of the welcome page of codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncomment:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf. Maybe even make it

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

Make sure to use FollowSymLinks

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and even make two virtual hosts.. one for domain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/domain
    ErrorLog C:/wamp/www/domain/logs/error.log
    CustomLog C:/wamp/www/domain/logs/access.log common
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and again for www.domain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/domain
    ErrorLog C:/wamp/www/domain/logs/werror.log
    CustomLog C:/wamp/www/domain/logs/waccess.log common
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

be sure you've created all the folders for the log files.

And btw I'm not 100% sure all of this will work.

Good resources on this topic:

[Wamp Server: Multiple Virtual Hosts are not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530418/wamp-server-multiple-virtual-hosts-are-not-working-on-windows)

http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2007/08/16/setting-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp/