# Access virtual host from another machine over LAN

Tags: windows, apache, windows-7, virtualhost, wampserver

- I am using Windows 7 with Wamp 2.2 server.
- I have setup 2 virtual hosts: `www.project1.com` and `www.project2.com`.
- I have modified the "*[hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))*", the [`httpd.conf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd.conf), and the [`httpd-vhosts.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) files, to the changes I mentioned below.

Using my browser, when I type `www.project1.com` or `www.project2.com`, I successfully get my web pages opened on the laptop that has the server installed on.

Changes in the "*hosts file*": I've appended the followings to the end of the file:-

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.project2.com
127.0.0.1       www.project1.com
```

Changes in the `httpd.conf` file:-

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Changes in `httpd-vhosts` file:-

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "D:/websites/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project1/"
    ServerName www.project1.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project2/"
    ServerName www.project2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Now; since I can open these web pages from a browser in `PC_1` (the one with the server), how can I access these web pages from a browser in `PC_2`? (I mean any PC connected to `PC_1` via LAN.)

Comment: I am new to all this and have a few more questions..

1.Is my above code appropriate for what i wish to achieve?
@Gabriel - with the above code and your suggestion to change the hosts file of another pc, it opens the wamp default page on typing www.project1.com

Comment: Yep, it's a normal way to do this. You can setup several ServerAlias options too, if you want to combine this with dynamic dns services, for example.

Comment: just refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530418/wamp-server-multiple-virtual-hosts-are-not-working-on-windows/17850423#17850423

i answer for it...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your virtualhost directive, change `127.0.0.1` to `*:80` and as Gabriel mentioned, add an entry to the hosts file in the other machine, adding your domain to be associated with the IP of your server.

When you put an explicit IP into the directive, apache will only listen on that IP - but the wildcard will tell it bind to all IPs available to it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project1/"
    ServerName www.project1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If your server is on 192.168.1.70 for example, then in the other machines on your lan, the hosts entry will look like:

```
192.168.1.70     www.project1.com
```

Restart apache and it should work fine.

As a note, when you are using virtualhosts, apache will use the first definition as a default for when it can't make a match between the domain passed in the HTTP request header and the sites setup in the config, which is why your default page was appearing.

You told apache to bind to all IPs with the `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive, but then didn't setup a site for that external IP. Hope that helps!

Comment: How can you make it so you can use ipaddress/virtualhostname from any LAN machine, without editing the visiting machine hosts?

Comment: What if you want to test this from an iPhone for example? Is there any other way than changing the hosts file?

Comment: This works when I want to access localhost vhost entry of the server machine, how to access project1 and project2 both parallely from client machine on network?

Answer (score 38):

In addition to danp's answer, you can access the virtual host without having to change the client machine's etc/hosts file *by assigning a port to the virtual host*. This is ideal if you want to access the server with a mobile or tablet device:

1. Edit server's `httpd.conf` file at:

   ```
   \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.x\conf\httpd.conf
   ```

   Search for "`Listen`" (around line 61). You should see the following that allows for Apache to listen for port 80:

   ```
   Listen 0.0.0.0:80
   Listen [::0]:80
   ```

   Add the following lines to add listening for port `81` (or any port):

   ```
   Listen 0.0.0.0:81
   Listen [::0]:81
   ```
2. Edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file at:

   ```
   \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.x\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```

   Change your *"Virtual Host"* tag to port `81`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:81>
       DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project1/"
       ServerName www.project1.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Restart Apache server.
4. On the client machine/tablet/mobile, on the web browser, enter the server's IP address (`192.168.0.10`, or whatever IP) followed by the port number in the following format:

   ```
   http://192.168.0.10:81
   ```

Comment: Perfect, I would just add that on windows you may need to open the port 81 for wamp (inbound rules) in the firewall

Comment: I am also sticking with ports. If only there was a way, to make a windows machine known in the local LAN under serveral hostnames (either in some router DNS settings or elsewhere), would be much more elegant...

Comment: Beautiful solution across all devices. Killer solution :) Tested and proven. Thanks

Comment: Best solution. But in step 2 I didn't change but added the virtual host with the same name and path but with port 81. Otherwise servername didn't work on local PC.

Comment: This does not work in case i want to host multiple apps in htdocs. Is there a way that i could also access myapp.test on other PC in my network?

Answer (score 6):

There are two computer in local network.

A computer(192.168.1.70) Setup(D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project1/"
    ServerName www.project1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project2/"
    ServerName www.project2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

B computer Setup(c:/windows/system32/drives/etc/hosts):

```
192.168.1.70    www.project1.com
192.168.1.70    www.project2.com
```

B access A,My project is working.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of updated points to consider for the selected answer:

1. `NameVirtualHost` is no longer used after Apache version
   [2.3.11](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) and can be omitted.

   > In 2.3.11 and later, any time an IP address and port combination is
   >   used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is
   >   automatically enabled for that address.
2. Because we are talking about hosting a website over LAN, let's set a
   requirement* to only accept connections from IP addresses on your
   local network. For example, on a common Linksys router, the default
   IP assigned to each device on the network is between 192.168.1.100
   to 192.168.1.255. You can allow connection from all devices on the
   LAN with an IP address 192.168.1.XXX by using `Require ip 192.168.1`
   (notice the final octet is left off the IP to allow the entire
   range).

   This allows you to configure access per project so that one may be
   available over LAN and another is only available locally.

   ```
   # This will allow all LAN connections to www.project1.com
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project1/"
       <Directory  "D:/websites/project1/">
           Require local
           Require ip 192.168.1
       </Directory>
       ServerName www.project1.com
   </VirtualHost>

   # This will allow only the machine hosting the website to access www.project2.com
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "D:/websites/project2/"
       <Directory  "D:/websites/project2/">
           Require local
       </Directory>
       ServerName www.project2.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   While your site will not be served publicly without the router forwarding traffic on port 80 to your host, I believe this is considered best practice. It is especially necessary if you need to control which projects are available to devices on the LAN.
3. Reminder: Your host machine should be configured to use a static IP address
   instead of being assigned one by your router's DHCP. Since we are
   editing the hosts file of other devices to point to the server's IP,
   we don't want it to change.

<sub>* I'm including this because it is common to have access restrictions on a local development server and you will need to specifically make it available to your local network.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the hosts file on the machine you're trying to view the page from.

So you need to add them to the hosts file on the other lan machine.

Comment: with the above code and your suggestion to change the hosts file of another pc, it opens the wamp default page on typing www.project1.com
How do i make it go to the index page of www.project1.com?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to access your virtual host server in your local area network then check you have configured your firewall to allow httpd.exe file (lying in folder C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\bin) to allow both incoming and outgoing connections

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).