# How to access localhost (wamp) from another computer or device

Tags: apache, web-services, localhost, virtualhost, wampserver

I need to acces a project in wamp from, another pc and an android device.
I tried looking it up in the internet nothing worked so far

Comment: Localhost is local to that computer.

Comment: yes i know, like i said, i fixed the computer ip adresse to 192.168.1.250, but even in my own computer it says : "You don't have permission to access / on this server." the said error when i try from a different pc or from my phone

Comment: Anyway, you need to configure you virtualhost to accept requests to other host names than `localhost`. Try adding `ServerAlias 192.168.1.250` to its config, besides the `ServerName` directive. Then restart Apache.

Comment: @BigRabbit Oh, ok - didn't see that from within the review queue

Comment: I tried that solution @Jost it didn't work either :(

Answer (score 2):

Update your httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf file in the `<Document>` tags. mod_authz_core was introduced in Apache 2.3 and changed the way that access control is declared.

So, for example, instead of the 2.2 way of configuring `<Directory>`...

```
    <Directory "C:/wamp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**Order** and **Allow** directives have been replaced with the **Require** directive:

```
    <Directory "C:/wamp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Sources
 [Error with .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140559/error-with-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/06/fun-with-wamp-server-and-apache-2-4-2/
         http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: I already did that, i fixed my IP adresse to 192.168.1.250 but even in my own computer it doesn't work when i tri to access http://192.168.1.250, it tells me "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Comment: thanks @Maraboc but what you just said it's my default configuration, I already have that in my http.conf file

Comment: Is the icon of wamp green or not ??

Comment: yep it's green, in fact i can access my project from my own computer like localhost/myproject it's working just fine what i need to do is be able to access the same project from another comuter in the same network. and thanks for everything @Maraboc

Comment: Did you try to create a vertualHost if not i can update my answer ?

Comment: yes i tried creating a virtual host now instead of localhost i can access it with project.local/mypage but i can't with the ip adresse i think that if i want to access it from another computer it need to be with an ip adresse

Comment: Take a look at the first answer of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245242/access-virtual-host-from-another-machine) and let me know if it works ;)

Comment: if i understood well : i need to modify the host of the other computer ?

Comment: what about the android device ? how can i access the project from it's browser like chrome or something ?

Comment: the real phone, but the pc i'm just testing with my own pc i guess their's a solution if you have ten computer it'll take time to modify the host of every single one of them i think if i get it to work with the ip in the same network the problem will be solved even for the phone

Comment: Is th fireWall is deactivated? if not you must deactivated first.

Comment: yep it's deactivated i've been wondering in the internet for over 8 hours now i really did some research and i've tested everything so far. so basicaly my question is very simple how can i change this : localhost/myproject to this 192.168.1.250/myproject working for everything connected to the same network

Comment: I suggest to update your quation if there is some one else how can help you

Comment: Thanks @Maraboc for your time i'll post another question